# can't get keyboard to go away or input to register

Tags: objective-c, input, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a guessing game and for some reason I can't get the input to register when I transferred it from another file. The keyboard also won't go away. What's missing?

gameviewcontroller.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    int randomNum;
    int turns;
    id mons;
    IBOutlet UITextField *guessField;
    IBOutlet UILabel  *resultLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel  *playAgain;


}
-(IBAction)enterGuess:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;





@end
```

gameviewcontroller.m

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    turns = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)updateLevel:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    guessField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];
    resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];
    playAgain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];
    _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"guess-number.jpg"];
    turns = 0;
    if( guessField.text.length != 0 )
    {

        randomNum = arc4random() % 10;

    }
    else if ( guessField.text.length == 0 )
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"you did not enter a guess!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"try again" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)enterGuess:(id)sender{

    if( guessField.text.length != 0 )
    {
        if ([guessField.text intValue] != randomNum) {
            if ([guessField.text intValue] > randomNum) {

                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-down.png"];
                resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];
                playAgain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Try Again. "];
                turns ++;
            }
            else if ([guessField.text intValue] < randomNum){


                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"];
                resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];
                playAgain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Try Again. "];
                turns ++;

            }


        }
        else if ([guessField.text intValue] == randomNum){

            turns ++;

            if([guessField.text intValue] == 0){
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"which I guess is no pokemon at all. Sad day!"];
            }

            if([guessField.text intValue] == 1){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bulbasaur6.jpg"];

                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bulbasaur"];

            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 2){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ivysaur.jpg"];

                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ivysaur"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 3){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"venusaur.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Venusaur"];

            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 4){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"charmander.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Charmander"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 5){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"charmeleon.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Charmeleon"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 6){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"charizard.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Charizard"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 7){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"squirtle.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Squirtle"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 8){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wartortle.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wartortle"];


            }
            if([guessField.text intValue] == 9){
                _image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blastoise.jpg"];
                mons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blastoise"];


            }

            resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Congrats, you got pokemon # %i, %@. ", randomNum, mons];
            playAgain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter New Number to Reset and Play Again"];

            randomNum = arc4random() % 10;
            turns = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"you did not enter a guess!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"try again" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your `UITextFieldDelegate` methods. E.g.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Additionally, the fact that the input is not entered seems to indicate that you did *not* set the controller as the `delegate` of the text field.

To check that you have set the delegate correctly, put a breakpoint into `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`. If it is not called, you have not set the delegate as required. Also, try to put up a button that calls `resignFirstResponder`on the text field. In `textFieldDidEndEditing:` you can get the text from the field and process it.

Comment: I added this to gamecontroller and it's still not working. For some reason I can't get the enterguess to work and show the actual changes

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer. If the controller is the delegate of the text field it *must* call the delegate methods. See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[self.guessField resignFirstResponder];
```

to the `enterGuess` method.